# QR Code - Combine two QR codes that contain strings to be compared

Tags: qr-code

Say I have these two strings: `Is there 01A?` and `Is there 02A?`. I have a simple program that reads QR codes, and when it receives the string, it will search for a hard-coded list for the string and returns a `true` or `false`. Is it possible to not scan these two string of QR codes one at a time, but combine them together?

Comment: QR code can have multi-lines of text entry in a single code. [Is this what you meant](https://zxing.org/w/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chld=L&choe=UTF-8&chl=Is+there+01A%3F%0AIs+there+02A%3F)? After this of course your software / QR reader need to understand the multi-line entry and parse it somehow.

Comment: I see, so it's a matter of the way of parsing, not how it is compiled. Thanks.

Comment: Now I'm more interested in this. Is it possible to impose a delay, say I will scan the first string, after getting the result of that, proceed to scan the second string if my method only parses one string at a time?

Comment: That is a different question... but if your program can simply "read QR" and then get a multi-line text (say you read and store it in a variable), maybe you can then parse/separate the content into an array and then deal with each entry one at a time. One possible thing to separate is the CR/LF (if it is there) - I can't say for sure since I never make QR-code reader and not sure what result it come up with. Note: This additional question may be best answered in StackOverflow as they deal more into programming. I'll see if the mods can move this to SO.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help, I think that's fine for now.